# I can't figure out how to get display property to work when it comes to multiple div elements

Tags: css

Ok, so I am learning html/css and I have run into a problem.  It has to do with a div inside of another div inside of another div. I am trying to use display with the divs to see how I could use them if there was a situation where it might be necessary. I looked on the net but I couldn't find anywhere the answer. The only place where anything happens is when I place a display property under the 'div'element. But the other div's don't do anything.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<head>
</head>
<title>Practice the advanced elements/css3</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/display-properties.css">
<body>
    <div> 0
        <div id="container">1
            <div class="one">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
div{
border: 5px solid green;
background-color:  hsla(400, 100%, 50%, .50);
height: 300px;
width: 600px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 40px;
display: inline-block;
}

#container{
width: 100px;
border: 10px solid hsla(278, 100%, 50%, 1);
background-color: hsla(278, 100%, 50%, .50);
text-align: center;
font-size: 40px;
}

.one {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
border: 5px solid hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 1);
background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, .50);
text-align: center;
font-size: 40px;
}

.two {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
border: 5px solid hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 1);
background-color: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, .50;
text-align: center;
font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: The question is a little bit unclear. What isn't working? What have you tried, what is the expected result, and what problems are you experiencing?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: and your question is....

Comment: sorry for the lack of info.  I didn't know how to word my problem, but user3286962 answered my issue.  Next time I ask a question, though, I will make sure it is asked clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to place DIV(0) IN DIV(1) and DIV(1) should contain DIV(2) AND DIV(3) side by side. For That:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Practice the advanced elements/css3</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div style="height: 390px;padding: 50px;"> 0
    <div id="container">1
        <div class="one" style="display:inline-block;">
           2 
        </div>
        <div class="two" style="display:inline-block;">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
   </body>
   </html>



 <style type="text/css">
      div{
      border: 5px solid green;
      background-color:  hsla(400, 100%, 50%, .50);
      /*height: 300px;
      width: 600px;*/
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40px;

      }

  #container{
  /*width: 100px;*/
  border: 10px solid hsla(278, 100%, 50%, 1);
  background-color: hsla(278, 100%, 50%, .50);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  }

  .one {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 5px solid hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 1);
  background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, .50);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  }

  .two {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 5px solid hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 1);
  background-color: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, .50);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
   }
  </style>
```

[image: Output]

Note:The display property inline-block allows the div to tolerate other DIVS next to it, unlike display block. By default, DIV is display block; So if you place display:block or remove display:inline-block from class="one" and class="two" from my code then DIV(2) and DIV(3) will no longer be side by side; a block DIV can not tolerate other DIVS next to it, hence DIV(3) will fall on the next line.

Please take care of the width and height of the DIV. If the inner DIVS width or height is greater than the outer DIVS, the overall layout structure will turn out wrong logically, like in your case.

Hope this is what you were trying to asked.

Comment: Thank you!  You have solved my question.  I didn't know how to phrase it, because I didn't really know how to word my question, but you answered it for me. I didn't fully understand the rules for the DIV's and what the DIV and #container differences were but now I feel like I can grasp the concept. I will have to test it a little further in order to absorb it, though.

Comment: That is good news then. Try playing with <div> and <span> tags when applying display:inline, display:inline-block, display:block in its css. Read about it. And sooner or later, you will be comfortable. I also faced the same issues initially. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out this link on http://net.tutsplus.com and the related webdesign.tutsplus site.

On their network there's also a very good introduction course on CSS, but it's not free.

Anyway it's not hard at all.

You have a few types of elements: block, inline and online-block you'll use most. Others will be used as well as defaults.

Divs are block elements, so they normally take the while weight of their parent element and as much height as they need. To form complex layouts and columns sometimes we use float, which changes this by placing the div out of the page flow so other elements stack next to it.

That's a really rough and perhaps not accurate enough description, but should serve as a starting point.

Also definitely check this out: http://learnlayout.com It's an awesome explanation of CSS layouts by example.

Comment: You don't need to pay to learn css code, there are loads of good video playlists on Youtube you can learn from.

Comment: Thank you.  I checked out learnlayout.com and it looks like it will be very helpful.  I have also watched some videos on Youtube, which have also been very helpful, and I have finished the html/css courses on Codeacademy. I know I will probably be coming back often when I cannot find answers anywhere else.  This community is most helpful.